# how to pass images from one View to another View

Tags: ios

I am trying to pass image from one `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController`. but I'm not getting success.
My code is below.

```
  PostGameViewController *v1=[[PostGameViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@ "PostGameViewController" bundle:nil];
  v1.theImg = imgPicture;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:v1 animated:YES];
```

// in ".h"

```
@interface PostGameViewController : UIViewController{
UIImage *img;
UIImageView *theImg;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *theImg;

@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImage *img;

-(IBAction)clickFacebook:(id)sender;
```

//in ".m"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[theImg setImage:img];
}
```

Comment: Ishant Tiwari tried @sunny answer?

Comment: imgPicture is valid ?. can you post code of that also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i have pass String variable in anotherview same way you can use for image.

in MainView Controller:

```
UserDetailsViewController *userDetailsViewController = [[UserDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    userDetailsViewController.ID = idUser;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:userDetailsViewController animated:YES];
```

in `UserDetailsViewController`

in .h file

```
@property(nonatomic) NSString *ID;
```

in .m file (how use ID)

```
NSLog(@"ID---->%@",self.ID);
```

---

for image

```
UserDetailsViewController *userDetailsViewController = [[UserDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
        userDetailsViewController.img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:userDetailsViewController animated:YES];
```

in .h file

```
@property(nonatomic) UIImage *img;
```

Comment: Dear Dhawal i am trying to pass images.plz check my code. and tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
PostGameViewController *v1=[[PostGameViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@ "PostGameViewController" bundle:nil];
        v1.theImg.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:v1 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
PostGameViewController *v1=[[PostGameViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@ "PostGameViewController" bundle:nil];
v1.theImg.image = imgPicture;   
[self.navigationController pushViewController:v1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: showing waring incompatible pointer tpyes assign to UIImage from UImageView

Comment: please post code of image picture the only we will get clear idea

Comment: `UIImage *imgPictute = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"];`

Comment: you are missing the extension of file here . for e.g  UIImage *imageFromBundle = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagres.jpeg"]; , image must be referred with extension