# iOS 7 - Pass data (image) between ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a controller in which I take a picture using `UIImagePicker`, the taken picture is shown instantly in UIImageView. Well, what I wanna know is how can I pass this image to another viewController.

I know how to pass data between ViewControlller using `PrepareForSegue` method, but I don't know how to pass an image in the case stated above.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: What is different between passing an image or other data? Since you tell us you know how to pass data between ViewControllers? Just replace the data for `UIImage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a UIImage property in your destination view controller and then pass your image in prepareForSegue

Your destination view controller:

```
@interface DestinationController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage * image;
@end
```

prepareForeSegue in your sourceController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DestinationController *destination =(DestinationController*)segue.destinationViewController;

    destination.image = your_picked_image;
}
```

Comment: In this case `your_picked_image` will be what ? because it is not declared

Comment: your_picked_image is the image you want to pass to another controller. I mean it can be any image you want

Comment: It is fine, but I got a warning saying that : incompatible pointer type sending UIImageView to parameter of type NSString

Comment: `your_picked_image` is the image you want to access in your `DestinationController`. He's assuming `your_picked_image` is globally defined.

Comment: That would be what ever image you want to use. Thats just a place holder for the image you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

I `.h` file of the destination class:

```
@property(nonatomic) UIImage *img;
```

In the method the pushes to the destination viewController:

```
target.img = myImage;
```

You may also take a look at: [Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17419388/1091539), [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17419239/1091539), [Answer3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18470186/1091539)